# CakePhp 3 - link and save associations with a table which holds two foreign keys of same model

Tags: php, mysql, entity-framework, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

i have the following two tables:

**recipes**

[image: table-a]

**similiar_recipes**

[image: table-b]

As you can see similar_recipes has two foreign keys which both point to recipes. Now I want two things. First of the linking. I read on stackoverflow some similar stuff and come up with the following configuration:

**RecipesTable.php**

```
$this->hasMany('Recipes', [
    'foreignKey' => 'recipe_id',
    'className' => 'SimilarRecipes'
]);

$this->hasMany('SimilarRecipes', [
    'foreignKey' => 'similar_recipe_id',
    'className' => 'SimilarRecipes'
]);
```

**SimilarRecipesTable.php**

```
$this->belongsTo('Recipes', [
    'foreignKey' => 'recipe_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER',
    'className' => 'Recipes'
]);
$this->belongsTo('SimilarRecipes', [
    'foreignKey' => 'similar_recipe_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER',
    'className' => 'Recipes'
]);
```

The configuration should be correct. Now the other question is the correct associated saving or lets ask better is it possible to do the following:

**Recipes Data**

[image: table-a-entries]

Now in Cake I want to add a recipe and the associated recipes which are delivered in the `request->data` as an id-array

```
$newRecipe = $this->Recipes->newEntity();
$newRecipe = $this->Recipes->patchEntity($newRecipe, $this->request->data);

$this->Recipes->save($newRecipe, ['associated' => ['SimilarRecipes']])
```

This should be the result:

[image: table-b-entities]

In conclusion I saved a new recipe which gets the id 3. In the `request->data` I select the similar recipes 1 and 2.

Could someone give me an advice. Is my configuration wrong. Or what do I have to pass to the save method? By the way I don't get any errors.

Comment: The naming is kinda confusing, some real world names would probably have been better... so what you want to do, is to save a `table_a` (`TableA`) record, with two associated `table_b` (`TableBFirst`) records, each with their foreign key to `table_a` (`TableASecond`) set? Are you by any chance trying to create a self-joining many-to-many relation?

Comment: Yeah that doesn't sound right - are you sure you can't add 2 separate records to table b, each one with the correct tablea_id? That would have to be the way to do what you're meaning here..

Comment: Ok so I changed the naming from table-a to recipes and table-b is now similar-recipes. The idea is now that you can add a new recipe and you can say which existing recipes are similar to the new one. Is this better understandable?

Comment: Definitely better, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use `belongsToMany` associations instead

I'd say your association approach is wrong (or at least makes things unnecessarily complicated), I'd suggest to use `belongsToMany` associations instead, as what you seem to create there is a self-joining many-to-many relation.

Name the table `recipes_similar_recipes`, that's the convention CakePHP uses, it helps to avoid association name conflicts/confusion, and allows relying on magic configuration. Your tables associations/configuration should then look something like:

**RecipesTable.php**

```
$this->belongsToMany('SimilarRecipes', [
    'foreignKey' => 'recipe_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'similar_recipe_id',
    'joinTable' => 'recipes_similar_recipes'
]);
```

**SimilarRecipesTable.php**

```
$this->table('recipes');
$this->primaryKey('id');

$this->belongsToMany('Recipes', [
    'foreignKey' => 'similar_recipe_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'recipe_id',
    'joinTable' => 'recipes_similar_recipes'
]);
```

With such a setup you could then use the array of IDs variant, eg use the `_ids` key to define the existing (similar) recipies that should be associated with your new recipe, ie the request data should look something like:

```
[
    // there is no title column in your example,
    // this should just clarify the data structure
    'title' => 'New recipe that will get the ID 3',
    'similar_recipes' => [
        '_ids' => [
            1, 2
        ]
    ]
]
```

which should populate the `recipes_similar_recipes` table like:

```
+----+-----------+-------------------+
| id | recipe_id | similar_recipe_id |
+----+-----------+-------------------+
| 1  | 3         | 1                 |
| 2  | 3         | 2                 |
+----+-----------+-------------------+
```

You should then also consider making `recipe_id` and `similar_recipe_id` a compound primary key, or at least create a unique index with them.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Associations - Linking Tables Together > BelongsToMany Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongstomany-associations)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Converting BelongsToMany Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-belongstomany-data)**

Comment: Your suggestion sounds great. I changed everything to your answer. But unfortunately I got the error: "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test.similar_recipes' doesn't exist" when I am on the recipe add action. The configuration are completly like you did. The form has echo $this->Form->input('similar_recipes._ids', ['options' => $similarRecipes]); for the multi-select. Did I forget something?

Comment: @StephanHofmann I'd guess that either the `SimilarRecipesTable` class is missing the `table()` call that configures it to use the `recipes` DB table, or the `SimilarRecipesTable` class cannot be loaded for whatever reason (typos, permissions, etc), and therefore is an [**auto-table**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#disabling-generic-tables) (an instance of `\Cake\ORM\Table` instead of an instance of a concrete subclass thereof), check DebugKits SQL Log panel for a list of auto-tables present.

Comment: I baked my code that's why the naming of the files were incorrect. So the naming was RecipesSimilarRecipesTable instead of SimilarRecipesTable. Now everything works like a charme. Thanks for your dedication. This helps me a lot